# Difference between two regex patterns to find words ending with 'ing'

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.6

I am trying to find words ending with 'ing' in the following  
sentence = "Playing outdoor games when its raining outside is always fun!"

Now this is not my question itself as I found the necessary regex pattern to do it- **`(r'\b([A-z]+ing)\b')`.**

The thing is I'm unable to understand why the above works but not what I tried below:

`re.findall('([A-z]+ing)$',"Playing outdoor games when it's raining outside is always fun!")`

## Returns empty list even though the below doesn't

`re.findall('([A-z]+ing)$','amazing')`

## Returns amazing

So this pattern can match single words ending with 'ing' but not words in sentences? Why?

What I found even more weird is this:
`re.findall('\b([A-z]+ing)\b',"Playing outdoor games when it's raining outside is always fun!")`
returns no matches (empty list). The only difference is not using the raw string notation (r)

I thought the 'r' notation was only necessary when we want to escape backslashes. So in that case:
Pattern1 - **'\b([A-z]+ing)\b'** should match playing, raining etc. instead of
Pattern2- **r'\b([A-z]+ing)\b'**
What exactly have I understood wrongly? I searched a lot of Stack Overflow answers and the official Python regex documentation and now I am more confused than when I started out particularly regarding the use of **'r'**.

Comment: `findall('([A-z]+ing)$'` will return only those words that are at the end of the sentence. If your sentence ends up with a punctuation mark, you'll get nothing. Remove `$` sign that searches for the the end of the string for better results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$` matches end of line or end of whole text (depending on flag setting, here: only end of text). Using it right after the "ing" forces that the "ing" must appear at the end.

Raw string notation lets the escaped characters like `\b` go through to the underlying function (here: `findall`) to be processed further (here: as a special regex code for word boundary).

Without raw string notation, `\b` is the BACKSPACE control code (hex `0x08`). This character is processed by the regex engine as a simple match of itself.

Using `[A-z]` to match all letters is also not right. It actually means to match any character in the Unicode table between `A` and `z`. As you can see [here](https://unicode-table.com/en/#basic-latin) this includes e.g. `[`, `^` and `\`. If you only want the ASCII letters, use `[A-Za-z]` instead. If you want all Unicode word characters (letters and digits in any supported language and underscore) use `\w`.

To play around with regular expressions there is e.g. https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I particularly didn't know this about $. I had assumed it only matched at the end of every word. 
Accepting this answer :)